# Python save images from URL to different folders with custom name and structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a .csv file with image urls, and I need to save each image in a different folder like the tree in URL. For example, here 3 URL

```
https://citynews.stgy.ovh/~shared/uploads/files/794/794964898449/62325865102181/logo_1.pic
https://citynews.stgy.ovh/~shared/uploads/files/420/42030573107817/62325865102181/logo_1.pic
https://citynews.stgy.ovh/~shared/uploads/files/218/21897603939378/62325865102181/logo_1.pic
```

I need that every image is saved in a different folder tree named as path url, like this:

- image 1 -> folder /uploads/files/794/794964898449/62325865102181/
- image 2 -> folder /uploads/files/420/42030573107817/62325865102181/
- image 3 -> folder /uploads/files/218/21897603939378/62325865102181/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
import os
import urllib.request as urllib2

BASE_DIR = "C:\\workspace"

urls = ["https://citynews.stgy.ovh/~shared/uploads/files/794/794964898449/62325865102181/logo_1.pic",
        "https://citynews.stgy.ovh/~shared/uploads/files/420/42030573107817/62325865102181/logo_1.pic",
        "https://citynews.stgy.ovh/~shared/uploads/files/218/21897603939378/62325865102181/logo_1.pic"
        ]

for url in urls:
    split_path = url.split("~shared/")[1]
    img_name = os.path.basename(split_path)
    dir_name = os.path.dirname(split_path)
    path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, dir_name)
    print(path)
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
    urllib2.urlretrieve(url, os.path.join(path, img_name))

print("done")
```

Also, read this link: [python-os-makedirs](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-makedirs-method/)